# Why the state attribute is initiated before return?

Tags: reactjs

In some react implementations i see this way of use state attributes inside render function:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <span>this.state.name</span>
      <span>this.state.age</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Other way is use like this:

```
render() {
  const { name, age } = this.state;
  return(
    <div>
      <span>name</span>
      <span>age</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Is there any reason to use the second way, one is better than another or it doesn't matter ?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In first approach:

- `this.state` is accessed every time
- get new/updated value on each new line when state changes

In second approach:

- `this.state` is accessed single time
- get the new/updated value from the cached variable
- and the key benefit is to follow the eslint rule:
  [Prefer destructuring from arrays and objects](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring)

Comment: Very good, it makes more sense to use the second approach now, in the case of ESLint, which I am not using in my project, but it is a necessary implementation in the future, so is good to know.

Comment: Only one doubt, when a state attribute is changed, only that element, lets say a div, will be rerendered, or all elements inside render function will be rerendered?

Comment: All at once, it just about performance in my answer - that's what you might be confused.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer the second way, doing the destructuring, cause:

- When you are reading the component code, you will know all the component states that will be used for rendering the component;
- It will let your rendering function simple and easier to read, focusing only on what to render, not in how to render;
- Also is good for DRY principles (Don't repeat your self) cause you won't need to repeat this.state...

But it's not a rule :)
You can use whatever you and your team feels more comfortable...

Comment: It makes more sense now, but I wonder if the use of const is intentional to avoid any asynchronous problems that might appear using state or changing it, if there is one of course.

Comment: @ViniciusFrança nah, there's no way anything async could impact it. Nothing async is happening.